# How to efficiently implement optimisation of ordinal parameters in Matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization

I have an optimisation problem for `k > 1` parameters `x_1`, `x_2`, ... , `x_k` with an ordinal relationship. That is, `x_1 < x_2 < ... < x_k`, and I wish to minimise the cost function `f: (x_1, ... , x_k) -> c`.

Is there a Matlab optimisation algorithm which can be efficiently adapted to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use `fmincon()`? Have a look at the first example [here](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html): with the following, slightly amended constraints (here, for simplicity `k = 3`):

```
x(1) <= x(2) -> x(1) - x(2) < 0
x(2) <= x(3) -> x(2) - x(3) < 0
```

`A` and `b` according to the above equations could look like this:

```
A = [1, -1, 0; 
     0, 1, -1;
     0, 0, 0];
```

and

```
b = 0;
```

Note, however, that these are not strictly smaller than relations, because `fmincon` works with smaller or equal. To approximate a 'real' smaller than, you could introduce a very small number, say `e` in your above equations, for example

```
x(1) + e <= x(2)
```

If you make e small it should be an alright approximation.